# how do I bind the repeating codes shared by multiple forms in c#

Tags: c#, dll, module, parent-child, repeat

- I have around 10+ child forms and all the child forms have the following features

1. Close button: on hover displays "close" text and when mouse clicked, shows a message box to confirm the action
2. Minimize button: On hover, it displays "minimize" text, when the mouse is clicked, the form gets minimized
3. Drag anyway inside the parent form

- I have to avoid using Visual Studio's default style to get a desirable customized form.

-The code below is shared by all the child forms, since the code is the same, is there a way to bind to one place and reference?

code

```
public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
public const int HTCAPTION = 0x2;
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

 //Dtrag the form
        private void DragPanel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                ReleaseCapture();
                SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, 0);
            }
        }

       #region controlbox
        private void minimizebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }
        private void closebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Close the window?", "Close", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Close();
                //Application.Exit();
            }
            
        }
        
        private void closebtn_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip ToolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();
            ToolTip1.SetToolTip(this.closebtn, "Close");
        }

        private void minimizebtn_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip ToolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();
            ToolTip1.SetToolTip(this.minimizebtn, "Minimize");
        }
        #endregion
```

Comment: You can write an interface having these default methods, then your form just implements this interface then bind these methods to form events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a base class which itself derives from Form. Your actual forms should then derive from that base class.